# Git: "Error: refusing to create funny ref 'HEAD' remotely" for initial push

Tags: git, egit

I am attempting an initial push of my Git repository from Egit (Eclipse Git) to GitHub. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
error: refusing to create funny ref 'HEAD' remotely
```

I set both the source and destination ref to 'HEAD'

What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I fixed this by selecting master (refs/heads/master) as the source ref instead. Egit then automatically set the destination ref to master as well. I suppose that this command tells git to create the master branch, while selecting HEAD either tries to create a branch called HEAD or tries to push to the current (non-existing) remote HEAD.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the "master [branch]" item from the Source ref list will insert "refs/heads/master" into the Source ref field.

Before:

[image: "master [branch]" item in Source ref list]

After:

[image: "refs/heads/master" inserted in Source ref field]